# Active state apply when table open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply an active state to a table link when open.. I have it so that it hovers orange, but I want it to stay orange, and when closed revert back to blue. This also needs to be able to apply to multiple tables/triggers on one page.

I am not a JS developer so have no knowledge in this.

Here is a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yn1dmzmr/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.drop-table').hide();

    $('.open-table').each(function() {
        $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).next('.drop-table').slideToggle(200);
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
/* DROPDOWN ICON FOR THE TABLES STYLES */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

.open-table div {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 250px;
  background-color: #404E6A;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff!important;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-indent: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.open-table div a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.open-table div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.open-table div:hover,
.open-table div:active {
  background-color: #ff6600;
}

.open-table div:hover:after,
.open-table div:active:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.open-table div:hover {
  background-color: #ff6600;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ff6600!important;
}


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
/* COMPARISON TABLE STYLES */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

.comparison-table {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  table-layout: auto;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.comparison-table td {
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 13px 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.comparison-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container lb-margin">
    <a href="#" class="open-table">
        <div>Overview</div>
    </a>
    <div class="drop-table">
        <table class="comparison-table">
            <tr>
                <td width="200">Etching</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
                <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="200">Etching</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
                <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="200">Etching</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
                <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="open-table">
        <div>Overview</div>
    </a>
    <div class="drop-table">
        <table class="comparison-table">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="col-1">
                <col>
                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td>Etching</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
                <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Etching</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
                <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Etching</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
                <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="open-table">
        <div>Overview</div>
    </a>
    <div class="drop-table">
        <table class="comparison-table">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="col-1">
                <col>
                <col>
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td>Etching</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
                <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Etching</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
                <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Etching</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
                <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
                <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying `active` to the anchor element. Given your layout, you need to add it to the `div` instead.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/f9k9jn7s/1/)

```js
//Table Show / Hide Code 

 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.drop-table').hide();

  $('.open-table').each(function() {
      $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
          // This is only needed if your using an anchor to target the "box" elements
          e.preventDefault();
          
          // Find the next "box" element in the DOM
          $(this).next('.drop-table').slideToggle(200);
          $(this).find('div').toggleClass('active');
      });
  });
 });
```

```css
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
/* DROPDOWN ICON FOR THE TABLES STYLES */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

.open-table div {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 display:block;
 max-width:250px;
 background-color:#404E6A;

 font-family: helvetica;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #ffffff!important;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-indent:30px;
 position:relative;
  
  a {
    text-decoration:none;
  }

 &:after {
  content:'';
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  position:absolute;
  right:15px;
  top:10px;
  z-index:9;

  background-color:#d3d3d3;
 }

 &:hover, &:active {
  background-color:#ff6600;

  &:after {
   transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
 }
} 

.open-table div:hover {
  background-color:#ff6600;
}
  
.active {
  background-color:#ff6600!important;
}


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
/* COMPARISON TABLE STYLES */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
.comparison-table {
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 table-layout: auto;

 font-family: helvetica;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #000000;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
 line-height: 26px;

 td {
  width:auto;
  text-align:center;
  padding:13px 0px;
  border-right:1px solid #d3d3d3;
 }

 tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:#d6d6d6;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container lb-margin">


  <a href="#" class="open-table"><div>Overview</div></a>
  <!--Close the table opener -->
   <div class="drop-table" >
       <table class="comparison-table">
        <tr>
         <td width="200">Etching</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
         <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td width="200">Etching</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
         <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td width="200">Etching</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
         <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
  <!-- Close the drop table area -->



  <a href="#" class="open-table"><div>Overview</div></a>
  <!--Close the table opener -->
   <div class="drop-table">
       <table class="comparison-table">
        <colgroup>
         <col class="col-1">
         <col>
         <col>
       </colgroup>
        <tr>
         <td>Etching</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
         <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Etching</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
         <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Etching</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
         <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
  <!-- Close the drop table area -->



  <a href="#" class="open-table"><div>Overview</div></a>
  <!--Close the table opener -->
   <div class="drop-table">
       <table class="comparison-table">
        <colgroup>
         <col class="col-1">
         <col>
         <col>
       </colgroup>
        <tr>
         <td>Etching</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
         <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Etching</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
         <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Etching</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
         <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
         <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
        </tr>
       </table>
   </div>
  <!-- Close the drop table area -->
  

 </div>
 <!--Close -->
```

Comment: @MhdAlaaAlhaj How do you mean? It's just missing some css in the snippet, maybe an external link. The fiddle is fine anyway, and doesn't affect the answer.

Comment: try to open one table you will see that the table styles have been gone, compare it with the PO answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add `.open-table.active div` instead of `.open-table div:active` so you are telling the browser that *I want to style `div` when `.open-table` have `.active` beside*, hence you don't have to use `!important`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.drop-table').hide();
  
  $('.open-table').each(function() {
    $(this).show(0).on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next('.drop-table').slideToggle(200);
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
/* DROPDOWN ICON FOR THE TABLES STYLES */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

.open-table div {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 250px;
  background-color: #404E6A;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff!important;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-indent: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.open-table div a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.open-table div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
}

.open-table div:hover,
.open-table.active div {
  background-color: #ff6600;
}

.open-table div:hover:after,
.open-table div:active:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.open-table div:hover {
  background-color:#ff6600;
}
.active {
  background-color:#ff6600!important;
}

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */

/* COMPARISON TABLE STYLES */

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
.comparison-table {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  table-layout: auto;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
.comparison-table td {
  width:auto;
  text-align:center;
  padding:13px 0px;
  border-right:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.comparison-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:#d6d6d6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container lb-margin">
  <a href="#" class="open-table">
    <div>Overview</div>
  </a>
  <div class="drop-table">
    <table class="comparison-table">
      <tr>
        <td width="200">Etching</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
        <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="200">Etching</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
        <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="200">Etching</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
        <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="open-table">
    <div>Overview</div>
  </a>
  <div class="drop-table">
    <table class="comparison-table">
      <colgroup>
        <col class="col-1">
        <col>
        <col>
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>Etching</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
        <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Etching</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
        <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Etching</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
        <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <a href="#" class="open-table">
    <div>Overview</div>
  </a>
  <div class="drop-table">
    <table class="comparison-table">
      <colgroup>
        <col class="col-1">
        <col>
        <col>
      </colgroup>
      <tr>
        <td>Etching</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
        <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Etching</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
        <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Etching</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A2</td>
        <td>Flat sheets up to A0</td>
        <td>Flat sheets anysize</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple update this:

```
.active {
   background-color:#ff6600!important;
}
```

to:

```
.active div {
   background-color:#ff6600!important;
}
```